Adjoint triplet induced by exact functor of stable categories
For $\mathscr{A}$ a small stable $\infty$-category, we can consider the following diagram:

where $\mathcal{Y}_\mathscr{A}$ denotes the ordinary Yoneda embedding $\mathscr{A} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathscr{A})$, while $\mathcal{Y}^\text{Sp}_\mathscr{A}$ denotes the stable Yoneda embedding, and $\text{Lex}$ denotes left exact functors. In particular, choosing the notation $\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{A}) = \text{Lex}(\mathscr{A}^\text{op}, \text{Sp})$ (this could be called the derived category of $\mathscr{A}$), we obtain a fully faithful embedding $\mathscr{A} \overset{\mathcal{Y}^\text{Sp}_\mathscr{A}}{\to} \mathcal{D}(\mathscr{A})$. In particular, by currying, we obtain a stable hom-functor
$$\text{Hom}_\mathscr{A} \colon \mathscr{A}^\text{op} \times \mathscr{A} \to \text{Sp}$$
Now for any exact functor $\psi \colon \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ between stable $\infty$-categories, there is an induced precomposition functor
$$\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{B}) \overset{\psi^\star}{\to} \mathcal{D}(\mathscr{A})$$
Now we want to prove the following theorem:

The proof, given by Cisinski in his handwritten lecture notes (the lecture is called "derived categories" and all the notes + video recordings are to be found on his website), starts off by saying:
$\psi^\star \colon \mathcal{P}^\text{Sp}(\mathscr{B}) \to \mathcal{P}^\text{Sp}(\mathscr{A})$ is well defined as a map of spectral presheaves (i.e. $\mathcal{P}^\text{Sp}(\mathscr{A}) = \text{Fun}(\mathscr{A}^\text{op}, \text{Sp})$) and has a right adjoint $\psi_\star \colon \mathcal{P}^\text{Sp}(\mathscr{A}) \to \mathcal{P}^\text{Sp}(\mathscr{B})$ (= right Kan extension along $\psi$). Now it is claimed that $\psi_\star$ sends $\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{A})$ to $\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{B})$ as it sends $M \colon \mathscr{A}^\text{op} \to \text{Sp}$ to
$$\psi_\star(M) \colon \mathscr{B}^\text{op}\to \text{Sp}, \qquad Z \mapsto \text{Hom}(\psi^\star \mathcal{Y}^\text{Sp}_\mathscr{B}(Z), M)$$
My first question is:

How does one obtain the formula for $\psi_\star(M)$? I know that if $\psi$ is space valued (an ordinary presheaf) one could use the end-formula for the right Kan extension $\psi_\star$ to get the analogous formula for space valued presheaves: Spelling this out, we have

and therefore

implies the claim by the space-valued Yoneda Lemma. I would suppose the proof could be given somewhat analogously of spectral presheaves by means of the stable Yoneda Lemma and some analogous end-calculus, but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

How can this be proven, and how does this imply that $\psi_\star$ maps $\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{A})$ to $\mathcal{D}(\mathscr{B})$?


When one follows the proof of the above theorem further, the left adjoint $\psi_!$ is to be constructed. For this one proceeds as follows:

So $L\psi_!$ is the desired left adjoint. Now after that it is claimed that


The statement
$$L\psi_!(\mathcal{Y}^\text{Sp}_\mathscr{A}X) \simeq \mathcal{Y}_\mathscr{B}^\text{Sp}(\psi X)$$
is the analogous spectral statement to the space valued version where we have $$\psi_!(\mathcal{Y}_\mathscr{A}X) \simeq \mathcal{Y}_\mathscr{B}(\psi X)$$ which again follows quite quickly from some coend yoga.

Again, for the spectral setting I have some troubles proving this. Is there a neat proof here ?



The key is the adjunction $\mathrm{incl}\colon\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{st}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{lex}\colon\mathrm{Sp}(-)$ whose counit at a finitely complete $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ is given by $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sp}(\mathcal{C})\to\mathcal{C}$. This allows you to lift all kinds of statements about left-exact functors to spaces to statements about stable functors to spectra.
I will write $y^\mathrm{st}$ and $y$ for the stable and non-stable versions of the Yoneda embedding, and $\mathrm{nat}$ for the spectrum-valued hom of $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})$. The latter is the $\infty$-category of spectrum objects in $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})$, where $\mathrm{Spc}$ is the $\infty$-category of spaces.
Hence, to check that $\psi_*(M)$ coincides with $\mathrm{nat}(\psi^*y^\mathrm{st}(-),M)$ it suffices to postcompose with $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sp}\to\mathrm{Spc}$ and check we have an equivalence in that case. This means we have to check that the functor
$$
\mathrm{Nat}(y^\mathrm{st}(-),\psi_*M)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}(\psi^*y^\mathrm{st}(-),M)\colon\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Spc}
$$
towards spaces of natural transformations coincides with the functor $\Omega\circ\psi_*(M)$. But the adjunction above implies that
$$
\mathrm{Nat}(y^\mathrm{st}(-),\psi_*M)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}(\Omega\circ y^\mathrm{st}(-),\Omega\circ\psi_*M)
$$
and $\Omega\circ y^\mathrm{st}\simeq y\colon\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Spc}$ by definition of $y^\mathrm{st}$, so we can conclude by the space-valued Yoneda lemma.
For the other statement, namely that $L\psi_!\circ y^\mathrm{st}\simeq y^\mathrm{st}\circ\psi$, we can again verify this upon postcomposition with $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sp}\to\mathrm{Spc}$. Since $\Omega\circ y^\mathrm{st}\simeq y$ and we already know how left Kan extension behaves in the space-valued case, it suffices to show two things:

that $\Omega_*\circ L\simeq\ell\circ \Omega_*$, where $\ell\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})\to\mathrm{Lex}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})$ is the left adjoint in the space-valued case;
writing $\psi_{!!}$ for the left adjoint of $\psi^*\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})$, that $\Omega_*\circ\psi_!\simeq\psi_{!!}\circ\Omega_*$.

The first statement follows from the fact that any left-exact $h'\colon\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Spc}$ is of the form $\Omega\circ h$ for some $h\colon\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Sp}$, so that we have
$$
\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Lex}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\ell(\Omega\circ -), h')\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\Omega\circ-,h')\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\Omega\circ-,\Omega\circ h)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})}(-,h)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{D}(\mathcal{A})}(L(-),h)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Lex}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\Omega\circ L(-),h')
$$
naturally in $h'$.
The second statement follows as follows: we can lift the functor $\psi_{!!}\circ\Omega_*$ to a functor $\pi\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})$. Then for any $g\in\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})$ we have
$$
\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})}(\psi_!(-),g)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})}(-,\psi^*g)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\Omega\circ-,\Omega\circ\psi^*(g))\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\Omega\circ-,\psi^*(\Omega\circ g))\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})}(\psi_{!!}(\Omega\circ-),\Omega\circ g)\simeq\mathrm{Nat}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Sp})}(\pi(-), g)
$$
which implies that $\pi\simeq\psi_!$, so $\psi_{!!}\circ\Omega_*\simeq\Omega_*\circ\psi_!$.
I don't doubt that with a bit more of a structured approach, you can set up the entire spectrum-valued (co)end calculus that you would want here.

Great answer! :) Thanks
